# ¿Cómo veo constantemente la última línea de un fichero que va cambiando?

Tags: bash, unix

Tengo un archivo Datos.txt que posee lo siguiente:

```
147 34 1 1
333 33 0 0
157 51 1 1
...
```

Este archivo cambia cada x tiempo, en que se agregan lineas al final.

Necesito obtener la ultima fila cuando se agrega. Osea el ultimo elemento actualizado

Usando `tail -F Datos.txt` puedo ver lo agregado pero esto me devuelve TODO, y yo necesito la última fila.

Agregando el `tail -1`, que deberia devolver la ultima fila del output, este me devuelvo algo inesperado, que es un mensaje de tail:

> tail: 'Datos2.txt' has been replaced;  following new file

pero ne me devuelve el dato.

¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La respuesta de @Jbeltran es la mas practica, pero si sólo quieres ver el último dato puedes usar `watch`.

```
watch -n1 tail -1 Datos.txt
```

Que no monitoreara a cada cambio, sino a cada segundo; y veras únicamente una linea: la última línea del archivo "Datos.txt".

Referente a la última cuestión en tu publicación

En alguna ocasión en un trabajo me sucedió algo semejante y me llevó a leer el manual de `tail`. Lo que descubrí fue interesante.

El caso es que `tail` tiene los parametros:

- `-F`: que es el que tu utilizaste y que indica la instrucción `--folow=name --retry`,
- `-f, --folow[{name|descriptor}]`: que muestra la salida del archivo mientras este crece.

Hasta aquí ha diferencias muy importantes en el comportamiento del programa según los parametros. Con `tail -F archivo`, el programa devuelve en el output lo que se va añadiendo al archivo "archivo" pero lo vigila según su nombre. Es decir, si de pronto decides cambiarle el nombre a tu archivo, eliminarlo o truncarlo, entonces `tail` avisara lo que ocurrió.

`tail -F archivo` sólo sigue el nombre del archivo e intenta abrir una y otra vez el archivo señalado.

En cambio `tail -f archivo.log` es, por defecto, `tail --folow=descriptor`; el cual no sigue el nombre del archivo sino su descriptor de archivo, lo cual puede ser útil si estas monitoreando datos que se roten, por ejemplo, digamos que quieres generar una carpeta con archivos de registros y que deseas que cada uno de estos archivos tenga una longitud de, digamos, 10 lineas (o un tamaño exacto en bytes). Entonces cada 10 lineas cambias el nombre de ese archivo "archivo.log" a otro, digamos, "archivo.log.1", y creas otro llamado igual "archivo.log". Con `tail -f archivo.log` se monitoreara el archivo que inicialmente se llamaba archivo al momento de invocar `tail` y que luego se llamó "archivo.log.1". Mientras `tail -F archivo.log` monitoreara al archivo de **nombre** "archivo.log", `tail -f archivo.log` monitoreara a ese conjunto de datos que inicialmente estaban en "archivo.log" y que pueden cambiar de nombre de archivo; esto lo hace porque sigue a su descriptor de archivo.

Intenta hacerlo por tu cuenta.

Crea un archivo llamado `archivo` y metele basura desde una terminal; digamos:

```
 while : ; do; ((++i)); echo entrada $i >> archivo; sleep 2; done
```

Luego abre otra terminal y ejecuta:

```
tail -F archivo
```

y veras lo que se monitorea. Después, en la primera terminal, para el bucle y cambia el nombre del archivo con: `mv archivo nuevo_archivo`, y `tail` te indicara que el archivo "archivo" se ha vuelto inaccesible. En es caso deja corriendo el `tail -F` en la segunda terminal y en la primera vuelve a repetir el procedimiento inicial del bucle y veras que `tail` seguira *stremeando*.

En cambio, si utilizas `tail -f archivo`, no importa que le cambies el nombre a "archivo" por "archivo_nuevo": `tail` seguira la pista de ese conjunto de entradas.

Comment: Gracias por lo de watch -n1 tail -1 Datos.txt, funciona!! Respecto a -f o -F , me funciona -F no -f. Intenta crear un archivo y agregarle datos, lo hago con "sed -i '$a 902 55 0 0' Datos.txt" cunado  uso -f no me devuelvelos datosque agrego,cuano uso -F si, pero me devuelvetodo el archivo actualizado.Gracias!!

Comment: Perfecto. Si te funcionó mi respuesta marcala como la adecuada (y no sólo dale un voto) para que otras personas con la misma duda puedan encontrarla de utilidad y vean que funcionó.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes monitorear la ultima linea que va registrando tu archivo de esta forma:

```
tail -f -n -1 Datos.txt
```

Comment: Hola, eso sirve con -f pero no con -F que este ultimo es el que refleja la pregunta